# object message sent with Netty can't be decoded correctly

Tags: java, netty

I try to send object message `PingMessage` with netty. Add `ObjectEncoder` and `ObjectDecoder` in channel pipeline. Client has sent packet successfully, but server can't decode the message. ObjectDecoder#decode() just returns null. Netty version is 4.1.28.Final.

PingMessage

```
public class PingMessage implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int flag = 0xff3e;
    private String ping = "ping";

    public int getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(int flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    public String getPing() {
        return ping;
    }

    public void setPing(String ping) {
        this.ping = ping;
    }
}
```

client

```
public class HeartbeatInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<Channel> {

    protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast(new ObjectEncoder());
        pipeline.addLast(new ObjectDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE, ClassResolvers.weakCachingResolver(PongMessage.class.getClassLoader())));
        pipeline.addLast(new IdleStateHandler(BusinessConstant.READER_IDLE_SECONDS, BusinessConstant.WRITER_IDLE_SECONDS, 0));
        pipeline.addLast(new HeartbeatServerHandler());
        pipeline.addLast(new ClientHandler());
    }
}

public class HeartbeatServerHandler extends ChannelDuplexHandler {
        private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HeartbeatServerHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
        if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
            IdleStateEvent idleState = (IdleStateEvent)evt;
            if (idleState.state() == IdleState.READER_IDLE) {
            } else if (idleState.state() == IdleState.WRITER_IDLE) {
                try {
                    ChannelFuture future = ctx.writeAndFlush(new PingMessage()).sync(); 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

server

```
public class HeartbeatInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<Channel> {

    protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast(new ObjectEncoder());
        pipeline.addLast(new ObjectDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE, ClassResolvers.weakCachingResolver(this.class.getClassLoader())));
        pipeline.addLast(new IdleStateHandler(BusinessConstant.READER_IDLE_SECONDS, BusinessConstant.WRITER_IDLE_SECONDS, 0));
        pipeline.addLast(new HeartbeatServerHandler());
        pipeline.addLast(new ClientHandler());
    }
}

public class HeartbeatServerHandler extends ChannelDuplexHandler {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HeartbeatServerHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        if (msg instanceof PingMessage) {
            logger.info("received ping");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**netty source code debug info**

AbstractChannelHandlerContext#invokeChannelRead()

```
((ChannelInboundHandler) handler()).channelRead(this, msg);
```

the `msg` variable is

> UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 61, cap: 1024)

ObjectDecoder#decode() just return null

super class of `ObjectDecoder` is `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder`. LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder#decode() return null

```
// LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder#decode()

int frameLengthInt = (int) frameLength;
if (in.readableBytes() < frameLengthInt) {
    return null; // get executed and return null
}
```

Comment: We will need more infos but just let me say that `ChannelFuture future = ctx.writeAndFlush(new PingMessage()).sync();` will not work (and should even produce an exception) as you block the EventLoop. You should never call `sync*` or `await*` in the EventLoop

Comment: @NormanMaurer I've debugged the client code and no exception found. I use wireshark to capture packets and find "ping" packet which is 61 bytes. But the server just can't decode bytes to PingMessage. How can I provide more infomation? I don't post code about PongMessage(from server to client), which can be decoded well by client. Does Netty support both directions message processing?

Comment: @NormanMaurer I add `sync()` for debug purpose to assure that messages written without exception.

Comment: 1. You didn't add a `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` in your ChannelInitializer but mentioned it in your question. Why? 2. I tried your code and for me everything woks fine. Maybe you imported something wrong since all your classes have the same name.

Comment: @Ingrim4 `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` is super class of `ObjectDecoder`, so LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder#decode() get executed when `super.decode()` is executed in ObjectDecoder#decode(). client and server are two different projects, then it's ok when class names are the same.

Comment: Are you sure you have the same version of the serializable class on both class-path. ?

Comment: @NormanMaurer Yes.`PingMessage` is the same class with same package name in both sides. Does `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder#decode()` returning null provide useful info? In the `decode()` method, condition `if (in.readableBytes() < frameLengthInt)` is always true. `frameLengthInt` is a very large integer when debugging. How can I provide more info to resolve this problem?

Comment: When you say the same class with the same package name what does this mean ? Is it provided by a shared jar ?

Comment: @NormanMaurer Client and Server are two different projects. In both projects, they contain class `com.example.message.PingMessage`.

Comment: You should share a jar which contains the class between both project.s

Comment: @NormanMaurer client sends a String message "connected successfully" to server once connects, which causes the problem of decoding. Maybe messages are mixed. I didn't realize this. Everything works now.